# Using onClick to change background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have a menu that I'm using for a mobile website. My issue is that when you click to expand the menu, the only way to minimize or contract the menu is to click on the menu button again.

So, i want to make it more apparent to viewers that clicking on the menu button again will minimize it. My thinking is i will add a down arrow to menu before click, and an up arrow after.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7A6x9/).

Here are the arrows i want to use. [Arrows](http://postimg.org/gallery/8w9vfu9i/85b5f6b0/)

Html

```
<div id="menuclick" class="smenu_div">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul id='hiddenMenu'>
           <li><a href="/mobile/m.index.html">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="m.trucks.html">Trucks</a></li>
           <li><a href="m.equipment.hmtl">Equipment</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

CSS

```
 /*Mobile Menu*/
.smenu_div ul
{
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:35px; 
    margin-right:40px;
    font-family:georgia;
    font-size:60px;
    color:#ffffff;
    list-style:none;
    text-indent:15px;
    text-align:center; 
    width:35%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float:right;
}

.smenu_div ul li
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    line-height:justified;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position:relative;
}


/* Changed this so that your hidden menu is hidden by default */
.smenu_div li ul
{ 
  z-index: 50;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  float:none;
  }

.smenu_div ul li a
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    background: #000000;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
.smenu_div ul li a:hover
{
    color:#000000;
    background:#fdff30;
}
.smenu_div ul li#active
{
    position:relative;
    color:#000000;
    background:#fdff30;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var hidden = true;
    document.getElementById('menuclick').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('hiddenMenu').style.display = (hidden) ? 'block' : 'none';
        hidden = !hidden;
    };
```

Comment: your question is about how to make more apparent to viewers that clicking on the menu button again will minimize it (a UX/UI question) or how to implement the funcionallity itself (code)?

Comment: try using jquery mobile UI .. it is more easier to use and more of the functions which you desire are predefined...

Comment: by jquery mobile ui you would get something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7A6x9/2/)

to learn more about it refer [demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/)

Comment: Excellent. I am looking into the jquery mobile ui. It seems like you would have to "trim the fat" off the JS and CSS files to make them more approachable and customizable. What i mean is that to alter one section of code you would have to skim through a lot.

Comment: The immediate issue i have is that when you open the menu, the only way to close it is to click back on the main menu "button". Is there a way to make the menu close when clicking on anything but the menu?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kJE5F/2/, it now has the specified arrows.

The new CSS:

```
.smenu_div ul li a.menu-title
{
    background: #000000 url('http://s26.postimg.org/5szmru8r9/down.png') no-repeat right center;
    background-size: 48px 30px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

.menu-open .smenu_div ul li a.menu-title
{
    background-image: url('http://s26.postimg.org/rqw3lmnrp/image.png')
}
```

(Please don’t hotlink the image data as I did!)

And some new JavaScript:

```
document.body.classList.toggle('menu-open');
```

But I would change the arrow-images because they don’t play nicely with the colors of the button, take a look at these: https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=arrow&license=2&price=free.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will take your example to make something useable, until i find a better solution.